# DropDownListFor SelectList SelectedValue is not being Recognized

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working with a simple example of a call to `HtmlHelper.DropDownListFor()`, and the passed `SelectList` object has a default value indicated in the constructor:

```
SelectList MySelectList = new SelectList(MyCollection, "ValueField", "TextField", DefaultIdValue);
```

And then this `SelectList` object is passed into my view model into a strongly-typed view.

If I break on the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` call, I can see that indeed the `SelectList` object passed into the `DropDownListFor()` method invocation has the proper `SelectedValue` property set to the correct value field value.  And even through enumerating the select list items, I can see that the *correct* item has `Selected` set to `true`.  Yet, when this renders this selected value is not actually initially selected, it's still just the first item in the drop down listbox.

What could I be doing wrong here?  I've done all object verification, but this `SelectedValue` just doesn't seem to be *"recognized"* here.  Thank you in advance for the assistance!

**EDIT**

Here is my model (it's a viewmodel that is passed into a strongly-typed view)

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }
    public SelectList MyClassList { get; set; }

    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
    public int PreSelectedId { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have logic to determine the `PreSelectedId` in the action prior to pushing the viewmodel out to the view:

```
        PreSelectedId = // code to get preselected id.  Debugged and working

        SelectList TempList = new SelectList(MyCollectionOfObj, "Id", "TextField", PreSelectedId);

        return View(
            new MyViewModel()
            {
                MyClassList = TempList,
                MyClasses = // retrieves some objects here,
                PreSelectedId = PreSelectedId
            });
```

The actual selected value *visually* is the first element.  The actual selected value by breaking on the code and looking at the SelectList.SelectedValue is the correct one (the 5th item, for instance).  Visual and implementation are showing two different things, confusingly.

Comment: What does your model look like? What's the expected selected value, and what's the actual one?

Comment: You do not need the 4th argument of `SelectList` if your using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PreSelectedId, Model.ClassList)` - if the value of `PreSelectedId` matches one of the option values it will be selected. Or are you binding to `SelectedId`? Or are your using `DropDownListFor()` in a loop? It would help to show your view

Comment: Hmmm... That was the fix, and I'm not sure why.  I refactored `PreSelectedId` out, and populated `SelectedId` with the pre value and that worked.  I didn't know that was a requirement...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are trying to bind to property `SelectedId`, as in

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, Model.ClassList)
```

Since the value of `SelectedId` is `0` (you don't seem to be setting it anywhere) the helper tries to find an option with a value of `0`, which it cant, so the first option is displayed (it has to show something) which is why you often use the  overload of `@Html.DropDownListFor()` that adds the `"--Please select--"` label which has a `null` value.

Change you code to

```
return View(new MyViewModel()
{
  MyClassList = TempList,
  MyClasses = // retrieves some objects here,
  SelectedId = PreSelectedId // change this
});
```

and remove the 4th argument from the `SelectList` constructor (its not necessary since the purpose of the strongly typed helpers are to bind your model values)